# How To Get All Python Logs Only On Error?

Tags: python, logging

I am using pythons built in logging class. I'd like to only log out when an error occurs, but when it does, to log out everything up until that point for debugging purposes.

It would be nice if I could reset this as well, so a long running process doesn't contain gigabytes of logs.

As an example. I have a process that processes one million widgets. Processing a widget can be complicated and involve several steps. If processing fails, knowing all of the logs for that widget up to that point would be helpful.

```
from random import randrange

logger = logging.getLogger()
for widget in widgetGenerator():
  logger.reset()
  widget.process(logger)

class Widget():
  def process(self, logger):
    logger.info('doing stuff')
    logger.info('do more stuff')
    if randrange(0, 10) == 5:
       logger.error('something bad happened')
```

1 out of 10 times the following would be printed:

> doing stuff
>
> doing more stuff
>
> something bad happened

But the normal logs would not be printed otherwise.

Can this be done with the logger as is or do I need to roll my own implementation?

Comment: As a starter you should have a line like `logging.basicConfig(level=logging.ERROR)`.

Comment: For sure. And I can set it to that now. But if an error is logged I'm looking for a solution that will allow me to see all of the Info/Debug logs as well

Answer (score 0):

Use a `MemoryHandler` to buffer records using a threshold of e.g. `ERROR`, and make the `MemoryHandler`'s `target` attribute point to a handler which writes to e.g. console or file. Then output should only occur if the threshold (e.g. `ERROR`) is hit during program execution.